# compare and total row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to get the totals without the helper column in Excel?  Want to sum the difference between B to A. excel 98.52 < 98.53.

[image]

Values

```
A   B       Less    More
98.52%  98.53%      1   
100.00% 90.00%          1
90.14%  90.13%          1
0.00%   0.00%           
95.45%  96.45%      1   
0.00%   1.00%       1   
            
            3   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

For Less

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6<B1:B6))
```

For More:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6>B1:B6))
```

[image]